# C - 2D peak finder in

Tags: beginner, algorithm, c

This is an implementation of a 2D peak finder from MIT's Intro to Algos.

I'm a C beginner and I would really like some feedback on coding style, documentation and any other general C bad practices.
Additionally have I correctly freed the memory of the recursive calls?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct max_vector {
    unsigned int col_index;
    unsigned int row_index;
    int index_value;
} max_vector;


max_vector * find_col_peak(int *arr, int rows, int col){
    /* Find the peak of a column.
    
    This function treats a 2D array like a 1D array and
    traverses using some basic pointer arithmetic.

    next item = *((i * row + arr) + j)
    where:
        - i == current row number (the y axis in matrix i.e. up and down)
        - j == column number in column space (the x axis i.e left to right)
        - row == the number of items in each row
        - *arr == the first item in the array
    */

    // we want a vector to save the max number and its index
    max_vector *vector = malloc(sizeof(max_vector));
    
    if (vector) {
        // set max to the first item of the column
        vector->col_index = 0;
        vector->index_value = *(col + arr);
    
        // loop through the rest of the column
        for (int i=1; i < rows; i++){
            int next_number = *((i * rows + arr) + col);
            if (next_number > vector->index_value){
                vector->col_index = i;
                vector->index_value = next_number;
            }
        }
        printf("the max value is %d and it is at index %d\n",
            vector->index_value, vector->col_index);
        return vector;
    }
    return NULL;
}


max_vector * peak_finder(int *matrix, int rows, int first, int last){
    /* Find a local 2D peak.

    NOTE: Expects a matrix of size row x col

    A peak is defined as:
    (i, j) >= (i, j + 1), (i, j - 1), (i + 1, j) (i - 1, j)
    */

    max_vector *vector;
    
    int middle = last / 2;
    vector = find_col_peak(matrix, rows, middle);

    if (vector){
        if (middle == first || middle == last){
            vector->row_index = middle;
            return vector;
        }

        if (last > first) {
            int current = *((vector->col_index * rows) + matrix + middle);
            int one_less = *((vector->col_index * rows) + matrix + middle - 1);
            int one_more = *((vector->col_index * rows) + matrix + middle + 1);

            if (one_less <= current >= one_more) {
                vector->row_index = middle;
                return vector;
            }

            // if current is not a peak we can free the vector
            if (one_less > current){
                free(vector);
                return peak_finder(matrix, rows, first, middle - 1);
            } else {
                free(vector);
                return peak_finder(matrix, rows, middle + 1, last);
            } 
        }
        vector->row_index = middle;
        return vector;
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main(void) {
  int arr [5][5] = {
    {10, 8, 11, 10, 16},
    {14, 13, 12, 11, 24},
    {15, 9, 11, 21, 6},
    {16, 21, 19, 20, 12},
    {100, 6, 13, 19, 9},
  };

  max_vector *ptr = peak_finder(*arr, 5, 0, 5);
  printf("the local peak is at %d, %d", ptr->row_index, ptr->col_index);
  free(ptr);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Use standard array notation

When you are accessing array elements, the idiomatic way in C is to write `foo[bar]` instead of `*(foo + bar)`. So instead of:

```
int next_number = *((i * rows + arr) + col);
```

Write:

```
int next_number = arr[i * rows + col];
```

It is both shorted, and now it is clear what part the array pointer is and what part the index is.

## Avoid unnecessary memory allocations

It's perfectly possible in C to return a `struct` by value. This avoids having to call `malloc()` and `free()`, and you no longer have to worry about its memory leaking, nor have to check whether `malloc()` succeeded. You do it like so:

```
max_vector find_col_peak(int *arr, int rows, int col) {
    max_vector vector;

    // set max to the first item of the column
    vector.col_index = 0;
    vector.index_value = *(col + arr);

    ...

    return vector;
}
```

## About recursion

With the above you don't have to worry about freeing memory for `vector` anymore. However, recursive calls themselves could have some memory overhead, since each call needs some amount of space on the stack. With this algorithm, you only need `log2(cols)` recursion levels, so that won't be an issue even for huge inputs. Also, the compiler can turn these recursive calls into [tail calls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call).